# FCL Stack class thread safety and it's version field

Tags: c#, .net, stack, fcl

I discovered an odd implementation of Stack class in FCL.
As I see, Stack class provides SyncRoot property intended to allow external users to block the entire collection and work with it in a thread safe manner. But along with SyncRoot I discovered a private field _version incrementing by Stack class in modifying operations (Push, Pop, Clear). This field is utilized by StackEnumerator class to check if there were any changes while looping through a collection.
But what a surprize! Everywhere Stack class increments version by unary operator ++ without Interlock class using. So I quiete don't understand what is the intention of a version field?

Comment: I think you are correct.  `Interlocked.Increment` should be used.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745440/what-operations-are-atomic-in-c