# Synchronizing primitives

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, postsharp

In this [PostSharp Multithreading](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/examples/multithreading) example it states in Listing 6:

> Any method that modifies the object should be annotated with the
>   [WriteLock] custom attribute. Methods that read more than one field of
>   the object should also be annotated with the [ReadLock] custom
>   attribute. (**It is useless to synchronize methods or property getters
>   performing a single read access, because the operation is always
>   consistent.**)

What does it mean that it's useless to synchronize methods or property getters performing a single read access? Is that only true for simple primitives such as string, int, float, etc. or does it apply to structs as well? Or is it a misleading statement?

Comment: this is a bit misleading - as I understand it, assuming reading is safe, single read is ok. If you have object the some of this values depend on his other values, when read more than 1  property - need to add the above attribute. But this is me .....

Comment: As I understand they're saying that their Object is not ThreadSafe, therefore you have to do the synchronization yourself with Reader and writer locks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it talks about "operations on pointer size objects are atomic" - so if you make single read of reference OR accordingly sized `struct` you are guaranteed to have consistent value without locks.

Consistent means you can't get half pointer from old value of property and half from new value of a property. Note that it does not mean latest value - if you need latest value you still need synchronization of some sort.

For more detailed information [What operations are atomic in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745440/what-operations-are-atomic-in-c).