# In C#, what does "atomic" mean?

Tags: c#

I read this in the book C# 6.0 and the .NET 4.6 framework:

> “assignments and simple arithmetic operations are not atomic”.

So, what does it exactly mean?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/241017/what-is-atomicity)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What operations are atomic in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745440/what-operations-are-atomic-in-c)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability#Primitive_atomic_instructions

Comment: This article may help you http://wayneye.com/ViewBlog.aspx?Permalink=Atomic-Operation-In-Csharp

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745440/what-operations-are-atomic-in-c here are complete definition of your question.

Comment: I don't know what does atomic mean, so knowing what operations are atomic doesn't help me, if one of you write a book, there is a chance to have two titles in the chapter explaining this topic: 1: what is atomic? 2: what operation are atomic?
You can't start with the second title. Condemning my question as a duplicate version increase the possibilities to be blocked from the site, so please understand my question.

Comment: If you didn't understand my explanation, then tell my why and where, please. Giving examples for atomic operations and telling why they are atomic seems to be the most understandable approach. Furthermore, there are already many resources on the Internet about atomicity. Search them and you'll surely learn more.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Atomic operations are ones that cannot be interrupted partway through, such as by threading. Take for instance the statement

```
_value++;
```

If you have two threads executing this code at once with a starting value of `0`, you may have the following

- Thread A reads `_value`, 0
- Thread A adds 1, 1
- Thread B reads `_value`, 0
- Thread B adds 1, 1
- Thread A assigns to `_value`, 1
- Thread B assigns to `_value`, 1

so now, even though we've called an increment twice, the final value in `_value` is `1`, not the expected `2`. This is because increment operators are *not* atomic.

The function [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx), however, *is* atomic, so replacing the above code with

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref _value);
```

Would solve the given race condition.

**EDIT**: As a point of etymology, "atomic" *originally* meant "indivisible" - the chemistry term we're familiar with is a misnomer held over from the belief that atoms were indivisible, only for later discoveries to break them down further into subatomic, quark, and quanta levels.

Answer (score 11):

An atom is indivisible. Atomic operations are "indivisible" operations, which cannot be divided, e.g., interrupted.

Microprocessors do not execute sequentially, that is, instruction after instruction, just like written in a program. There are external objects, which can change execution flow. A good example are interrupts.

So, you may know the `MOV` instruction, which is available on pretty much all processors.
Imagine that it is executed by the CPU. a 32-bit value is moved into a 32-bit register.
Now, after 16 bits have been moved, an interrupt request occurs.

- An atomic `MOV` instruction will not stop but will execute to the end and **then** the CPU will handle the interrupt
- A `MOV` instruction that is not atomic will immediately be stopped and the interrupt is executed. The problem is, if the interrupt accessed the register, which was written to by the `MOV`, **the content is unclear** because the `MOV` operation is only half-finished!

Now, on usual processors, `MOV`s operating on the processor's word size are atomic. If a processor word is 16 bits wide, a 16-bit `MOV` instruction will be atomic.
However, a 32-bit `MOV` operation would not be atomic. Such a non-atomic `MOV` instruction is normally not provided by the instruction set but by some higher-level language as with C's `long long` or C#'s `long`. Operations on these data types are **not** guaranteed to be atomic!

Comment: Is there an example on this?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed Example added.

Comment: @cadaniluk: Many processors specify circumstances in which interrupts will not occur.  On an 80386sx processor (like an 80386, but with a 16-bit data bus), a 32-bit read or write will be performed as two 16-bit operations, but most kinds of interrupts cannot be serviced between them.  I think it might be possible for a bus fault to occur when the instruction is half-processed, but if such an interrupt occurs on a read, the value that was read in the first half of the operation will be discarded, and the entire read re-executed from scratch.  If a bus fault occurs mid-write, ...

Comment: ...the entire write would be re-executed from scratch, so that any write which completes will have done so atomically, *but* the write operation would end up writing the first half of the destination both before and after the page fault handler.  Most systems are designed, however, so that such a sequence of events could not occur if the access is performed at a multiple-of-four address.