# Intermittent exception thrown from CollectionViewProxy, an internal WPF type

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

The exception in question is one normally seen when a program modifies a collection from another thread:

> System.NotSupportedException: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

But this isn't a case of pushing the modifications onto the main thread. **The CollectionView in question is one of my own creation which *does* support cross-thread changes.**

After investigating, I found that the exception is actually thrown by a [`CollectionViewProxy`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/R/cb559f0155984ed5.html) object, one of which is created internally by WPF to wrap around my collection view.

This type's constructor sets a flag called `ShouldProcessCollectionChanged` to false, preventing itself from processing collection changed events (in [`OnCollectionChanged`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/R/10e80dc10cdd7097.html)). 99% of the time this works correctly, but somehow this check very occasionally passes, even though the proxy does **NOT** have that flag set (when the crash occurs the flags are `IsDynamic | NeedsRefresh`). When the check passes an exception is always thrown.

Has anyone seen this before? All I can think of is that there is some sort of contention going on where one thread is changing the proxy's flags (perhaps `NeedsRefresh`) as another reads them. But [integer operations are meant to be atomic in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745440/what-operations-are-atomic-in-c), and if that was going wrong it would surely be causing problems elsewhere too.

Comment: They are atomic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745440/what-operations-are-atomic-in-c

Comment: In this case we only care about reading/writing the value, not comparing or other interlocked operations.